# How would I correctly add my CSS loading texts into my css loading animation? I only see placeholder text

Tags: html, css

I am not sure how to format my html so it shows my loading texts instead of the "..." place holder I set.

```css
@keyframes loading-text {
  0% {
    content: "Pizza";
  }
  30% {
    content: "Burgers";
  }
  35% {
    content: "Chicken";
  }
  60% {
    content: "Hot Dogs";
  }
  75% {
    content: "Funnel Cakes";
  }
  90% {
    content: "Ice Cream";
  }
  95% {
    content: "Tacos";
  }
}

.loading-text {
  top: 205px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.loading-text:after {
  content: "Welcome";
  font-weight: bold;
  animation-name: loading-text;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.triangle {
  stroke-dasharray: 17;
  animation: dash 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0.04, 0.63, 0.95) infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 136;
  }
}

.loading {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  font-size: 7px;
  animation: blink .9s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 40 60">
      <polygon class="triangle" fill="none" stroke="#fc0303" stroke-width="1" points="16,1 32,32 1,32" />
      <text class="loading" x="0" y="45" fill="#fff">...</text>
    </svg>
<div class="scss-loader">
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/j12eqhuy/5/

I am not sure how I would link the css texts in place of the "..." string.I am very new with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<text>` element does not accept pseudo elements. Using `span` it can only be done with only css. Like this:

```css
@keyframes loading-text {
  0% {
    content: "Pizza";
  }
  30% {
    content: "Burgers";
  }
  35% {
    content: "Chicken";
  }
  60% {
    content: "Hot Dogs";
  }
  75% {
    content: "Funnel Cakes";
  }
  90% {
    content: "Ice Cream";
  }
  95% {
    content: "Tacos";
  }
}

.loading-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.loading-text {
  margin-top: -50px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.5em;
}

.loading-text:after {
  content: "Welcome";
  color: #fff;
  font-weight: bold;
  animation-name: loading-text;
  animation-duration: 12s;
  animation-iteration-count: 1;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100vh;
}

.triangle {
  stroke-dasharray: 17;
  animation: dash 2.5s cubic-bezier(0.35, 0.04, 0.63, 0.95) infinite;
}

@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 136;
  }
}

.loading {
  font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
  font-size: 7px;
  animation: blink .9s ease-in-out infinite;
}

@keyframes blink {
  50% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="loading-container">
  <svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 40 60">
    <polygon class="triangle" fill="none" stroke="#fc0303" stroke-width="1" points="16,1 32,32 1,32" />
  </svg>
  <span class="loading-text"></span>
</div>
<div class="scss-loader"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I didn't even consider a SPAN. Had no idea this was the correct way, obviously. I was under the impression it didn't matter. Thanks a million for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `.loading-text` in the CSS is matching anything.

`content` in CSS can only be used on psuedo elements, and I doubt they can be used within an SVG.

Answer (score -1):

With pure CSS, that’s impossible.

You'll have to use JavaScript to change the text.